# Is it a must to use deferred Facebook deep links to track app installs

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) has the following statement:

> When people tap the Open / Play button on the invite or the Is Ready installation notification, they will be taken to your app. The URL defined in the App Link will be passed in.

So I was expecting the url(`al:android:url`) defined in the app link to be passed. Here is the example of the app link from Facebook docs:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="couchinapp://invite_from_fb?referral=123456789" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Couchin" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.mycompany.couchin" />
<meta property="al:web:url" content="http://www.couchinapp.com/myapp.html" />
```

While experimenting with the app installs from Facebook app invite I discovered that the intent, which launches the app when notification is clicked, doesn't contain the deep link. The deep link is only present when my app was previously installed and Open button of the invite is clicked.

Is it an absolute must to use this code:

```
AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(
        activity, 
        new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                //process applink data
            }
        });
```

in order to track fresh installs?

Answer (score 1):

If the user clicks on "Install" from the app invite, and installs your app, and then later opens the app (from the home screen, for example), then the incoming intent will not contain the deep link, and you need to use fetchDeferredAppLinkData to get the deep link.

If the user clicks on "Open" from the app invite, then it should have the deep link in the intent.

Comment: is it possible to delete the info, we get from fetchDeferredAppLinkData, again, after we used it once? I get this info now after every app start or app reinstalltion. I use the Facebook Android SDK 4.19.0